# How to send the post to my FB wall

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have simple html page and need to post data (title/text) from that page to my (I'm logged in) FB wall

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Send the post to FB</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Title: <input type="text" id="tbTitle" /><br />
            Text: <input type="text" id="tbPostText" /><br />
            <input type="button" value="Send to FB Wall" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ but there is not simple code how to do that. Who can help me with solution. Thank you!

Comment: Try the [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

Comment: There is no simple way. You'll have to write the PHP code. Here is the detailed tutorial http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/5-steps-to-publish-on-a-facebook-wall-using-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

just grab values from text boxes and pass them into script described below:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/